# Why does "savior" have an "i"?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation-vs-spelling, suffixes, derivational-morphology

*Savor* or *saver* (cf. *[lifesaver](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lifesaver)*) both seem more plausible.  Why is there an *i* before the -or ending?

Comment: "More plausible"? Why? What's the context?

Comment: -er and -or are the standard endings in this formation.

Comment: Ah, I see! The question is why one who saves files or money is a saver, but one who saves souls if a saviour. Good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, the history of the word's form is as follows:

> **Forms**:  ME sauveur, ME sauveour, ME saveour(e, ME sauveor, saveor, saviur, savour, safeoure, Sc. safare, saweoure, ME, 15 sauvour, savioure, ME–15 savyour(e, ME savyowur, ME–15 savyor, 15 salveour, salviour, Sc. salvior, salweour, ME, 15–17 (18 chiefly U.S.) savior, ME– saviour.(Show Less)
>
> **Etymology**:  < Old French sauveour (modern French sauveur) = Provençal salvador, Spanish salvador, Portuguese salvador, Italian salvatore < late Latin salvātōr-em, agent-n. < salvāre to save v.

The English form has changed (including being *savour* for a time), but from the history you can see that the vast majority of forms have had *i* or *e* or even *y* to maintain the pronunciation. This is because the word comes from the Old French *sauveour*, so English spelling has maintained much of its root.